# meteor js event not firing on mobile

Tags: javascript, meteor

Login Template

```
 <div class="bigcircle">
         <div class="circle">
         <br>
         <p>Connect with facebook</p>
         <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Login JS

```
Template.login.events({
    'click .bigcircle':function(){
        console.log("clicked login")
    }
});
```

The event fires fine when using chrome on my laptop. it does not fire from safari on my iphone 6s. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading up on this, it looks like the Meteor events are wired up with jQuery, which doesn't support touches.

A lightweight library that you can include is [jQuery Fingers](https://github.com/chetan51/jquery.fingers)

Answer (score 0):

Add the fastclick package to your meteor application to get the events firing.  (It's a package provided by the Meteor Dev Group. I'm one of those people who prefer "official" packages instead of 3rd party).

```
meteor add fastclick
```

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/fastclick